# How can I mark a location on a map by clicking a button

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I want to make it so when a button is clicked, the current location of the device is saved. Then, a pin is displayed on the map at the current location. How do I do this? I am using swift.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var myPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
        println("Updating Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")

        myPosition = newLocation.coordinate



        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0009, 0.0009)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, span: span)
        Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but don't abuse xcode tag. it's for IDE issues. Please show your codes.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the authorization request correctly, your `locationManager didUpdateLocation` should set the `myPosition` property.

Add a button to your `ViewController` and create `IBAction` to handle touch up inside event. In the IBAction you call `Map.addAnnotation`. The added annotation has several properties, namely `coordinate`, where you use your `myPosition`.

Before you start adding the annotations, make sure that your `locationManager didUpdateLocation` is really working. There are some things that need to be handled, like properly checking for authorization and added `NSLocationWhenInUseDescription`...

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are saying. I am a beginner at programming.